# Grep rest of line.....after match

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep

I have a file containing only two lines, with the following structure:

```
$ cat /tmp/pwpower.log
000D6F0000D34227, -114.10
000D6F0001A405C4, -130.09
```

The values are power values of my solar plant. Negative value means generation.

I would need the values extracted via grep/sed/awk - whatever is the smartest way. I need to have both values extracted separately and without the minus sign.

What I do now is kind of stupid but it works - I'm sure many of you will have smarter ways for me :-) Here of course I only see the values plus Minus.

To get the first value:

```
cat /tmp/pwpower.log |grep -o "\-.*" | head -n 1
```

To get the second value:

```
cat /tmp/pwpower.log |grep -o "\-.*" | tail -n1
```

And related question, is there a simple way to take these STRINGs and transform so that I can calculate the SUM ?

Answer (score 12):

All values:

```
$ awk -F '[ -]*' '$0=$NF' /tmp/pwpower.log
114.10
130.09
```

Value on first line:

```
$ awk -F '[ -]*' 'NR==1{print $NF;exit}' /tmp/pwpower.log
114.10
```

Value on second line:

```
$ awk -F '[ -]*' 'NR==2{print $NF;exit}' /tmp/pwpower.log
130.09
```

Sum of all values:

```
$ awk -F '[ -]*' '{sum+=$NF} END{print sum}' /tmp/pwpower.log
244.19
```

Comment: Your FS doesn't need to be that complicated: `-F-` will do.

Comment: For more complex input, if you don't know if preceding fields have spaces, you can use a comma as the field separator and run the whole thing through `tr -d "- "` first.

Comment: @glennjackman The way I interpret the question is that the value can be non-negative (no generation) which breaks with just `-F-`.

Comment: Indeed, I hadn't read that closely.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `cut` to select the 2nd column of numbers, and `paste -sd+` to create a series of numbers to add together. The tool `bc` can then be used to do the calculation.

```
$ cut -d',' -f2 pwpower.log | paste -sd+ | bc
-244.19
```

#### How it works

Selects the numbers from the 2nd column.

```
$ cut -d',' -f2 pwpower.log 
 -114.10
 -130.09
```

Re-formats them into a single line with a `+` sign in between each number:

```
$ cut -d',' -f2 pwpower.log | paste -sd+
 -114.10+ -130.09
```

Performs the calculation:

```
$ cut -d',' -f2 pwpower.log | paste -sd+ | bc
-244.19
```

To get the absolute value:

```
$ cut -d',' -f2 pwpower.log | sed 's/-//g' | paste -sd+ | bc
244.19
```

If the format of the file `pwpower.log` is guaranteed you can have `cut` do the omitting of the minus sign:

```
$ cut -d'-' -f2 pwpower.log | paste -sd+ | bc
244.19
```

Answer (score 6):

A KISS approach

```
$ awk '{print -$2; t+=-$2}; END{print t}' pwpower.log 
114.1
130.09
244.19
```

Comment: KISS? What is that?

Comment: Keeping it Simple and Stupid ;)

Comment: @sim yes but unless I misread, the OP specifically asked for the sign to be removed

Comment: @steeldriver - ah yes my bad, I missed that sentence buried in there.

Comment: Keep it simple, stupid. To imply when you don't keep it simple, you are being stupid.

Answer (score 4):

I like your grep command, but it could be improved to remove the minus sign, and work in cases when there is no minus sign.  Extended regular expressions available in GNU grep  with the `-E` flag allow us to match a number more precisely.

It is slightly more efficient not to use cat, but pass the file name as an argument to the first command and let it read the file.  It also occurs to me that if you are dealing with just the first or last lines from the file, it makes more sense to use the `head` or `tail` commands first so that you only have to match one line with `grep`.

First value:

```
$ head -n 1 /tmp/pwpower.log | grep -oE '[0-9\.]+$' 
114.10
```

Last value:

```
$ tail -n 1 /tmp/pwpower.log | grep -oE '[0-9\.]+$'
130.09
```

Sum (with awk command from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450799/shell-command-to-sum-integers-one-per-line)):

```
$ grep -oE '[0-9\.]+$' /tmp/pwpower.log | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
244.19
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[root@ip-10-186-149-181 ~]# cut -d '-' -f2 /tmp/pwpower.log | paste -sd+ | bc
244.19
```

This will do the calculation without the minus.

I think cut is faster than awk, in general

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is the right tool, but the number probably *can* be positive (right?), which means you do *not* want to use the minus sign as a field separator.  Instead, use the comma as the field separator, then negate each value numerically -- `awk` will automatically convert strings to numbers for you:

```
$ awk -F, '{ print -$2 }' < /tmp/pwpower.log
114.1
130.09
```

If there happen to be any positive numbers, they'll come out negative.  If you only want the sum, `awk` can do that too:

```
$ awk -F, '{ sum += -$2 } END { print sum }' < /tmp/pwpower.log
244.19
```

Comment: In awk you can use `sqrt($2^2)` as a trick to get absolute value.

Comment: @JasonC That's clever, but in context I believe it would be the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

To sum the two values:

```
(awk -F- '{printf "%s+", $2}' /tmp/pwpower.log; echo 0) | bc -l
```

Comment: This all is a bit redundant. Why on earth nog use the calculation options of `awk`?

Comment: yeah, true, but i like `bc` =)

Comment: Ohw, well, then why use `awk`? `echo $(cut -d- -f2 file | tr '\n' '+')0 | bc`

Comment: @Bernhard Well, why use `cut`? Use `[insert_cmd_here]` instead, generate a subshell loop, invent new maths, use a human cluster or mental arithmetic, pipe my thoughts into `bc`. Why do we do things? No reason to make my answer bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed also

```
$-sed -r 's/[^-]+.(.*)/\1/g' /tmp/pwpower.log
```